# Updating Master table information based on Detail table status

Tags: mysql

I have one master and one detail table as following

```
Master:-
   BatchID
   BatchStatus
Detail
   DetailID
   BatchID
   DetailRecordStatus (Possible values 1,2,3)
```

I am trying to write a single a query that can update the Batch Status in Master based on `detailRecordStatus` values equal to 2 or 3

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Update with join?

For example..

UPDATE TABLE1
JOIN TABLE2
ON TABLE1.SUBST_ID = TABLE2.SERIAL_ID
SET    TABLE2.BRANCH_ID = TABLE1.CREATED_ID
WHERE TABLE2.BRANCH_ID IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

I have tried following solution in MySQL and i worked for me

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS batch_to_update AS
        ( SELECT DISTINCT br.batch_id FROM `batch_requests` br
        INNER JOIN `batch_requests_detail` brd ON 
        br.`batch_id` = brd.`batch_id`
        WHERE brd.`processing_status` = 2 AND brd.`processing_status` NOT IN (0,1) AND `success` = 1);
UPDATE `batch_requests`
SET `batch_status` = 2 
WHERE `batch_id` IN (SELECT batch_id FROM batch_to_update);
DROP TABLE batch_to_update;
```